# Delete self component with the button inside the component itself in Livewire 3

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

I am using livewire 3.
I have a button inside a component and i want to delete the component with that button which is also inside the component.

InvoiceRow component:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
 <button wire:click="confirmDelete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
 </div>
```

```
public function confirmDelete()
 {
  $this->dispatch('deleteRow');
 }
```

CreateInvoice component:

```
#[On('post-created')]
 public function deleteRow(){
 //  i want to know what to do here so i can delete the component??
 }
```

```
<div class="mt-5">
 @foreach (range(0, $rowCount - 1) as $index)
  @livewire('invoice-row', ['index' => $index], key($index))
 @endforeach
  <br>
<button type="button" wire:click="increaseRowCount" name="addRow" class="btn btn-success float-right">Add New Row</button>
 </div>
```

i want it to add the component on add new row button which is working fine but now i want a delete button which is present inside the component itself so how to achieve it.